# mySQL create table

Tags: mysql

After reading the tutorials and examples on creating tables, I'm trying to create my own. But, the error this code gives me doesn't tell me what is wrong.

Can someone help?

```
CREATE TABLE feedback
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT CREATE PRIMARY KEY,
email VARCHAR(80),
brand VARCHAR(30),
model VARCHAR(30),
desc VARCHAR(255),
date TIMESTAMP(8));
```

Comment: um, could you provide that error? It may not help you, but it probably will help us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing the primary key declaration wrong, I believe. Leave off the word "create" and it should work.

Comment: That did it! Thank you! I think the "desc" column name was a problem as well (Thanks nr4bt).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

desc VARCHAR(255),

"desc" is a reserved keyword, It might the problem, use something else and try

Hope it helps

Comment: There were two problems, as it turns out. That was one of them! Thank you! I got it working!

Comment: While `desc` is reserved, you can still use it if you write it like: `\`desc\``

Comment: @bazmegakapa: but it's not a good idea to use reserved words. Even though quoting is working, it is more hassle than it's worth

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I agree. Still good to know it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE  `feedback` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`email` VARCHAR(80),
`brand` VARCHAR(30),
`model` VARCHAR(30),
`descr` VARCHAR(255),
`date` TIMESTAMP
)
```

Comment: Yeah. I just fixed that. Sorry. That was a typo. It still doesn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

I usually put my keys at the end of the create. That way if I have many keys, it's easier to follow.

```
CREATE TABLE  `feedback` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` VARCHAR(80),
  `brand` VARCHAR(30),
  `model` VARCHAR(30),
  `descr` VARCHAR(255),
  `date` TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```